# What is the APP­KEY in Truecaller API?

Tags: android, api, security, authentication, mobile

I need to verify the spam score of mobile numbers using Truecaller API .I found documentation [here](https://dev.truecaller.com/docs) . In the API URL , I need to send a `APPKEY` , But how to get that ? there is no **registration** page for Truecaller API .

```
https://api.truecaller.com/v1.0/search.json?userKey=APP­KEY&phone=NUMBER
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

You should Read this Document for [Name Search API](https://dev.truecaller.com/docs#/name_search_api)

it Says that....

> The one thing to keep in mind is that all requests to our API require
>   authentication. For that, you will need to use a User Key (userKey)
>   along with your requests. These access details basically associate,
>   your server, script or program with a specific application. All
>   requests to the API must be made over SSL (https:// not http://).

It means you have registered Truecaller developer account then **Do Login** and get your **Access Key(USER KEY)** and pass it everytime you request to access API..

But I Think Truecaller API is not accessible for public users...

Read This Article for More Details : http://www.3scale.net/2013/05/truecaller-api-search-among-over-600-million-phone-numbers-worldwide/

Comment: Yeah , But there is no registration page in true caller site

Comment: Its Because it is not accessible for all users...see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?
[callerpy](https://github.com/Logic-gate/callerpy)
Here is the explanation from the developer:

```
Truecaller Name Retriever.
Since my request for the API was rejected, I commenced using python parsing libraries.
Callerpy emulates the process one would encounter if using a web-browser.
```

I tried it, and it works like a charm from the command line.

Comment: That code used to work, but unfortunately, Truecaller closed the api access through that login method.